# Homogeneous non-differential equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How can we know whether or not an equation is homogeneous in case of equations which are not of differential type?
For example this equation is said to be homogeneous in x, y and z.

$lx^3y+mxy^2z+ny^2z^2=0$

But how can we tell? What if we increase the number of variables? Is there a way?

Answer (score 1):

Replace $x,y,z$ with $ax, ay,az$ and if  $a$ cancels from equation it is homogeneous or scale invariant.

Answer (score 0):

A homogeneous function of degree $k\in {\mathbb Z}$ is a function $\phi(x, y, z)$ such that for all $\alpha \in {\mathbb R}$ or ${\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}}$ one has
$$
\phi(\alpha x, \alpha y, \alpha z) =  \alpha^k \phi(x, y, z)
$$
A homogeneous equation of degree $k\in {\mathbb Z}$ has the form
$$
\phi(x, y, z) = 0
$$
where $\phi$ is homogeneous of degree $k$.

When $k \in {\mathbb R}$ is not an integer, one often use *positively homogeneous* functions that satisfy the equality only when $\alpha> 0$